# tmux prefix key not working on mac OS High Sierra

Tags: macos, key, tmux, prefix

I installed tmux (3.1c) with Homebrew and when I type `C-b ?` I get the message

`-bash: C-b: command not found`

but when I press `ctrl + b` and ? it works. I also ran

`tmux show-options -g | grep prefix`

which displays

```
prefix C-b
prefix2 Invalid#1fff00000000
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you literally typing <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>b</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>/</kbd>

`C-b` is another way of writing `ctrl + b` - they both mean the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> keys. Typing <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> will not trigger any tmux commands; this is by design.

> but when I press `ctrl + b` and `?` it works

That is the expected behavior. If that is not your goal, you should edit your question.

Comment: When I read the tmux manual, I thought that I could type `C-b ?` in the terminal as an alternative of pressing ctrl + d + ?. I realise that it is just an abbreviation to refer to those keys that is used in the manual.

Comment: What part of the manual made you think that?

Comment: [This](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki/Getting-Started#the-prefix-key) paragraph

Comment: I don't understand how "The default prefix key is C-b, which means the Ctrl key and b." lead you to believe typing capital C hyphen b would work.

Comment: That was what I thought when I read the manual.. Anyway, thank you for commenting